# Selenium ChromeBrowser get() method doesnt work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-3.6

After I start a program, it automatically raises this error. Any idea how to fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/StyleZ/PycharmProjects/SpamBot/AddToGroup.py", line 13, in <module>
    browser.get(base_url)
  File "C:\Users\StyleZ\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 324, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\StyleZ\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\StyleZ\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64)*
```

Comment: we're going to need to see the code that raised this error

Comment: Navigate to a valid url instead of an invalid one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the stacktrace you posted it says **"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"**, so make sure you are passing a valid URL to *get()*

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
```